# requestLocationUpdates throws exception

Tags: android, service, gps, locationmanager

I am creating a service that periodically updates the position. but using the following code, it throws me:

runException Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

This code is running inside doInBackground of Async class in service

```
private void UpdatePosition()
    {
        locManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


        Location location = 
                locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        showPosition(location);
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                showPosition(location);
            }
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){

            }
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){

            }
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){
                Log.i("LocAndroid", "Provider Status: " + status);

            }
        };


        locManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 15000, 0, locationListener);
    }
```

I was reviewing several posts and found that request has to run in uithread, but do not know how or where to put it.

what can i do?

EDIT:

i'll add only this to my code and now isnt throw any error

```
private void UpdatePosition()
    {
        Looper.prepare();
        looper = Looper.myLooper();
        locManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


        Location location = 
                locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        showPosition(location);
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                showPosition(location);
            }
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){

            }
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){

            }
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){
                Log.i("LocAndroid", "Provider Status: " + status);

            }
        };


        locManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 15000, 0, locationListener);
    }
```

but i dont know if its correct..what do you say?

Comment: Can you post the full exception and stacktrace so we can get a better view of the problem.

Comment: Also are you trying to update the GUI in the showPosition method when called from the doInBackground or on a location update callback?

Comment: Does your AsyncTask do anything else or does it only work with the LocationListener?

Comment: in showPosition I just convert the latitude and longitude in a format I need. But I have no contact with UI. @hardillb

Comment: my AsyncTask its listening my server, waiting to receive the order to send position. when I receive the order, call UpdatePosition to get the data @Sam

Comment: i try to use that u told me @Sam..
but only add it? I have to configure anything else? it throwing me this: java.lang.RuntimeException: Only one Looper may be created per thread

Comment: I just found these, using `@Sam` didn't send me a notification... I took my answer down because I saw a couple flaws with it. So your code runs, but you're not sure if it works?

Comment: Sorry i didnt know it.. well I did several tests, but only works once, and then starts throwing errors.

Comment: finally working. just had to use this http://stackoverflow.com/a/13826448/1848285