# GPS Location on Service - Android

Tags: android, service, background, gps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [requestLocationUpdates throws exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13810662/requestlocationupdates-throws-exception)

I'm trying to create a service that when the server ask me, send my location. but can not find the way to do it, since everything is a background service. and I do not need to have UI interface. when I call requestUpdate () throws me an error and stops the application

```
locManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 15000, 0, locationListener);
```

**runException Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()**

How I can run something to update the position from my service?
anyone have any example or something to help me? I have not much experience yet.

Comment: Please do not repost questions: [requestLocationUpdates throws exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13810662/requestlocationupdates-throws-exception). Read the [FAQ#bounty] and [ask] to see acceptable ways to bring more attention to your existing question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, its famous problem, See response in your Exception:

```
 ... that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

You need provide  application's main looper.

Here is valid implementation:

```
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                        15000,
                                        0,
                                        locationListener,
                                        Looper.getMainLooper()
                                        );
```

Comment: apparently is working!!!. Now I just need to check if it update the position. I have to leave the office to review the changes. thank you very much. whatever happens I'll tell you.